# Java to Scala type conversion - collection of reflected classes

Tags: java, scala, reflection

I use `org.reflections` to scan a package in my project and get all classes that extend a certain trait, like so:

```
val reflections = new Reflections("classpath")<br>
val classSet = reflections.getSubTypesOf(classOf[Validation])
```

I end up with a `util.Set[Class[_ : Validation]]`
If i do `classSet.toSet.map(x => x.getName -> x).toMap` using `JavaConversions` i get a 'missing parameter type' error.
If i do `classSet.toSet.map(x => Map(x.getName -> x)).reduce(_ ++ _)` i get the same error.
If i replace the `toSet` to `toList` i get a 'type mismatch' error.
if i do `classSet.toList.map(x => (x.getName, x)).toMap`, i get the following error: 
 `Cannot prove that (String, Class[?O]) forSome { type ?O <: com.common.Validation } <:< (T,U). not enough arguments for method toMap: (implicit ev: <:<[(String, Class[?0]) forSome { type ?0 <: com.common.Validation },(T,U)])scala.collection.immutable.Map[T,U]. Unspecified value parameter ev.`

I want to convert this set to a map of the class name as key and the reflected class as value.
Note - when i build a map like:`var classMap = Map[String, Class[_ <: Validation]]()` and then pushing every element into this map, by iterating over the `Set`. I can't access the class's methods i implemented from the `Trait`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What helps in such cases in to explicity specify the types when using the `toSet` and `toMap` conversions:

```
import org.reflections.Reflections
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

trait Validation

val reflections = new Reflections("classpath")
val javaClassSet = reflections.getSubTypesOf(classOf[Validation])
val scalaClassSet = javaClassSet.toSet[Class[_ <: Validation]]
scalaClassSet.map(x => x.getName -> x).toMap[String, Class[_ <: Validation]]
```

Comment: Thanks! works like a charm. i didn't know you can explicitly specify types that way.